# fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('u1')).nativeElement is not working in angular 5 for customised element tags

Tags: angular5

fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('u1')).nativeElement is not working in angular 5 for customized element tags whereas it works for basic tag like h1, button and as such

Comment: `fixture.detectChanges()` should be called

Comment: yes we call it for every test case but this fixture.debugElement works fine for basic tag like button,h1 etc., but not for our customized tags

Comment: The issue was that this was not assigned to DebugElement class and again we need to have DebugElement.nativeElement and i should have used debugElement.queryAll and not query.